# How to delete the extra onclick function without getting any errors in c#?

Tags: c#

I searched for a similar question and could not find any solutions. I am building a GUI based application in c#. I have a button and the onclick function for it. It is like this:

```
void button_choose_directory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Choose folder where client will download the files
{
    FolderBrowserDialog chooseDirectory = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    if (chooseDirectory.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        downloadDirectory = chooseDirectory.SelectedPath;
        client.downloadDirectory = downloadDirectory;
        textbox_save_directory.Text = downloadDirectory;
    }
}
```

I accidentally double clicked again to that button and another function was automatically created.

```
 private void button_choose_directory_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
```

Now if i delete this function program gives error and does not compile. How can i fix this? I do not want this unnecessary piece of code in my program.

Error message is like this:

```
FileTransferClient.Form1' does not contain a definition for    
'button_choose_directory_Click_1' and no extension method 
'button_choose_directory_Click_1' accepting a first argument of type 
'FileTransferClient.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an 
assembly reference?)
```

Thanks

Comment: Read the error message.

Comment: `CTRL+F` for `button_choose_directory_Click_1` and delete it. You've deleted method but it seems that there are still some event subscriptions.

Comment: @walkhard thanks, it looks like it automatically added an event subscription in another file. That works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could right click the function you want to delete and choose "find usages". Visual Studio will take you to where it is being used and you can delete  it first there.  Then you can delete the method.

Answer (score 1):

Add This:

```
this.button_choose_directory.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_choose_directory_Click);
void button_choose_directory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Choose folder where client will download the files
{
    FolderBrowserDialog chooseDirectory = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    if (chooseDirectory.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        downloadDirectory = chooseDirectory.SelectedPath;
        client.downloadDirectory = downloadDirectory;
        textbox_save_directory.Text = downloadDirectory;
    }
}
```

Remove This:

```
this.button_choose_directory.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_choose_directory_Click_1);

private void button_choose_directory_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the events in the properties window (flash icon). Delete the method name `"button_choose_directory_Click_1"` in the `Click` event. If the event method's body is empty, this deletes it as well. Otherwise delete the code manually.